# How to get opposite boolean value of variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = true;
```

How to get opposite value of `a` (false) and vice versa?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
>>> a = true;
true
>>> !a;
false
```

Comment: This works for `a = false` as well.  I wasn't sure at first.

Answer (score 55):

Use the [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)) operator:

```
!a
```

Comment: lol im so sorry if this bumps the post but this answer and its comments couldn't go unrecognized.

Comment: @zetlen i laughed hard

Comment: I upvoted because you're right, and you stuck it to their validation!

Answer (score 14):

This would be much easier

```
var b = !a
```

This would make true a false and false a true

Answer (score 4):

Something like this, perhaps;

```
function toggleFlag(value){
   var toggle = value ? false : true;
   return toggle;
}

var a = true;

a = toggleFlag(a);
```

Comment: This is entirely too complicated for something this easy.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: Considering how basic the question is, I'd be inclined to upvote the most complicated answers provided. But that's just me.

Comment: Dunno, Justin... The principle is easy to follow, and extensible, no?

Comment: I like this answer. ! is obscure and unreadable; this is better, more maintainable code.

Comment: That's how I see it, but !a is far more elegant, tbh.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
var a = !a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the "not" operator

```
var a = true;
alert(!a); //=>false
```

Answer (score -5):

Try like Below

```
var Boolify = require('node-boolify').Boolify;
var opp_var = !Boolify(myVar);
```

Refer [node-boolify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-boolify)

Comment: Bruh...........